# Codeigniter display in a view data from 2 different tables depending on an id from the view

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I will try to explain this as clear as possible:

Here is my Hobby Controller function which takes all the data I have about the posts for a hobby and displays this data in the group_homepage view.

```
public function group_homepage($hobby_id){
    $this->load->model('model_posts');

    $data['posts'] = $this->model_posts->get_all_posts($hobby_id);

    $this->load->view('group_homepage',$data);

}
```

The problem now is that for each post that I display in the view, I also want to display the user's profile picture and name (found in the USER table in my database) and also all the comments associated to that particular post (found in the COMMENT table in my database).

My group_homepage looks like this:

```
<ul id='news_feed'>
   <?php
    foreach($posts as $post){
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<div class='left_post'>";
            echo "<a href='".base_url()."/index.php/login/open_profile/".$user_id."'>";
            echo"<img src='".base_url()."/uploads/".**USER'S PHOTO**."' alt='profile picture'>";
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='right_post'>";
            echo $post->message_text;
            echo " <p class='post_details'>written by <span>";
            echo **USER'S NAME**;
            echo "</span>, ";
            $db = $post->timestamp;
            $timestamp = strtotime($db);
            echo date("d-m-Y, G:i", $timestamp);
            **DISPLAY ALL POST'S COMMENTS**
            echo "</p></div></li>";
    }

?>
</ul>
```

Do you have any ideas how I can retrieve this information based on each post and display it along with the other info I already have about the post?

The model function is pretty simple:

```
public function get_all_posts($hobby_id){
            $this->db->where('group_id',$hobby_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('post');
            return $query->result();
        }
```

I should also mention that my POST table has the following fields: post_id, user_id, timestamp, message_text, group_id and likes

Comment: you need to join as I am not an expert in code Codeigniter query builder you need to check the documentation on how to join tables and retrieve data from different tables.If you post the table structures I could give you the query to join the tables which could be converted to CI style easily later

Comment: Hi Abnik! Thank you for your prompt response. I am also aware of how to join the tables to get the data I need. My problem is how do I retrieve the $post->post_id from the foreach loop in the view and send it to the controller functions that will get the data I need based on the $post->post_id or the $post->user_id respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Before starting go through this user guide [codeigniter Active Record Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) , in your function

```
public function get_all_posts($hobby_id){
    $this->db->where('group_id',$hobby_id);
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = post.user_id'); //join with users table
    $this->db->join('comments', 'comments.user_id = post.user_id'); //join with comments table
    $query = $this->db->get('post');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now you will have all the data including user's profile and comments, make a loop and display as per your requirement. e.g to print name and picture to the view

```
 echo $post->name; 
 echo $post->picture; //you have to use image tag here to display user's picture.
```